# Mysql Query - increase values where value is greater than X but less than Y

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to change the value of a row in my database.

For example: it's called `USERID` and starts with `ID` 2000 and ends on user `ID` 3000. So I have 1000 Entrys. I wanted to change all `ID`'s, starting with a new number and increase +1 with each entry.

So that user `ID` starts with 5000 and ends at 6000 for example.

Is there any mysql query for this?

Comment: Is `USERID` a primary key?

Comment: yes its a unique primary key

Comment: For your example, are you just trying to add a constant to all the USERID fields in the range, or are you trying to also renumber them?  In other words, does user 2000 become user 5000 and user 2002 become user 2003, assuming that user 2001 didn't exist? Or does user 2002 become user 5002?

Comment: yes correct, userid 2000 would become userid 5000 and 2001 would become 5001. I just need to change all userids to a higher number. Starting from 5000 instead of 2000. The real reason is that I have to add a database to another one, with same structure. But both have same userids, so I have to change all numbers of other database. Like starting from 5000, since the other database ends at ID 5000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Entrys 
SET USERID = (USERID + 4000) 
WHERE ID >= 2000 
AND ID <= 3000
```

This code will add 4000 onto each of the USERIDs between 2000 and 3000, meaning they will be renumbered 6000, 6001 etc.